# Webpack errors after running `npm run update` in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I have run `npm run update` after that when we run npm run watch getting these errors

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[11].resolve has an unknown property 'fullySpecified'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, ignoreRootsErrors?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, preferAbsolute?, resolver?, roots?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
   -> Options for the resolver
 - configuration.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups['styles-public/css/app'] has an unknown property 'type'. These properties are valid:
   object { automaticNameDelimiter?, automaticNameMaxLength?, automaticNamePrefix?, chunks?, enforce?, enforceSizeThreshold?, filename?, maxAsyncRequests?, maxInitialRequests?, maxSize?, minChunks?, minSize?, name?, priority?, reuseExistingChunk?, test? }
 - configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'fallback'. These properties are valid:
   object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, cacheWithContext?, concord?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, ignoreRootsErrors?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, preferAbsolute?, resolver?, roots?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
   -> Options for the resolver
 - configuration.stats has an unknown property 'preset'. These properties are valid:
   object { all?, assets?, assetsSort?, builtAt?, cached?, cachedAssets?, children?, chunkGroups?, chunkModules?, chunkOrigins?, chunks?, chunksSort?, colors?, context?, depth?, entrypoints?, env?, errorDetails?, errors?, exclude?, excludeAssets?, excludeModules?, hash?, logging?, loggingDebug?, loggingTrace?, maxModules?, moduleAssets?, moduleTrace?, modules?, modulesSort?, nestedModules?, optimizationBailout?, outputPath?, performance?, providedExports?, publicPath?, reasons?, source?, timings?, usedExports?, version?, warnings?, warningsFilter? }
```

Comment: This *might* happen if you have your own version of webpack in your package.json rather than letting laravel-mix use what it needs. Any chance you can provide more details like a package.json file ?

Comment: I've run into something similar. But we didn't run npm/update... Basically laravel-mix/webpack aren't working after upgrading to laravel 8.x (we'd never used views/vue/mix before now)...

Comment: @apokryfos is correct worked.